# DataSnap and Database Connection / Login

Tags: delphi, authentication, delphi-xe2, firebird, datasnap

I am trying to work out the "right" way to establish a connection to my database from the server of my DataSnap application.

Each (most) of my tables in the database have fields (whose values are set via a trigger on insert and update) called Updated and Created (this is the current time stamp when the record is written) and updated_by and created_by which (should) contain the currently logged in user.

I want the user to 'login' from the client side such that these fields reflect the user who has logged in (and by extension, I'll get user authentication from the database, not just from the server).  I can handle the authentication to the server itself from the client ok handling the OnUserAuthenticate and OnUserAuthorize events on the server.  I am trying to then pass the credentials to my database so that the triggers can set the fields stated above correctly.

So what is the way to approach this scenario? I am wonder if the DSAuthProxyUser and DSAuthProxyPassword from the client can be used but I can't find much (any) documentation on how I would use that.  Do I establish a new connection for every user who connects? This seems most logical to me.  I'm not going to have a lot of concurrent users.  Tops 30.  Most likely 5-10.  But what is the "normal" way this is done?  I don't want to (hope I don't have to) pass in the username to each of my insert/updates to set the values in the tables.

I hope I have explained my situation clearly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used it yet, but it looks to me that the [`RDB$SET_CONTEXT()`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-set-context) and [`RDB$GET_CONTEXT()`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-get-context) introduced in Firebird 2 are what you need. Using these functions, you can set (and get) additional information specific to the user session (namespace `USER_SESSION`) or the current transaction (namespace `USER_TRANSACTION`). You can also retrieve additional system information for the current session (namespace `SYSTEM`), but that is probably not relevant for your case.

What you would need to do is call the `RDB$SET_CONTEXT()` method in that OnUserAuthorize event, eg using (as a query):

```
SELECT RDB$SET_CONTEXT('USER_SESSION', 'actualuser', '<name of user') 
FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

Here `'actualuser'` is the context variable we use. In your triggers you can then retrieve the name (assuming PSQL, with a declared variable `actualuser`)

```
actualuser = RDB$GET_CONTEXT('USER_SESSION', 'actualuser');
```

You can then use `actualuser` in the rest of your trigger. Just make sure you also account for the case where the context variable is not set (eg an administrator making direct changes to the database or something like that).

Comment: I guess one could also write `dummy_result = RDB$SET_CONTEXT('USER_SESSION', 'actualuser', '<name of user')` ?

Comment: In PSQL you can even do without assigning to a variable according to the documentation: "Due to its UDF-like nature, RDB$SET_CONTEXT can – in PSQL only – be called like a void function". But when running from SQL you will need to execute it as a query against `RDB$DATABASE`.

Answer (score 1):

Firebird has the CURRENT_USER keyword which can be used in SQL.

The example below is based on http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-current_user.html

```
create trigger bi_customers for customers before insert as
begin
  New.created_by  = CURRENT_USER;
end
```

To have the user name for updates, simply declare a before update trigger like

```
create trigger bi_customers for customers before update as
begin
  New.updated_by  = CURRENT_USER;
end
```

This solution requires a 1:1 mapping of database users to external users. In the most simple implementation, it means that the DataSnap session authenticates the user credentials against the database.

In your description however, it seems to be a two step authentification (first against the DataSnap layer, then against the database). I am not sure how this can be done regarding safe password handling, and if you plan to have a separate user/password table only for the first authentication stage (DataSnap) and a user login mapping from DataSnap to database as some kind of 'decoupling'.

Comment: As far as I understand the OP, there is a difference between the user of the database connection (which is `CURRENT_USER`) and the logical user of the application. The OP wants to log this logical user of the application, not the user of the database connection.